# Referencing external javaScript from php

Tags: javascript, php, html, undefined, external-js

I have a function named

```
test()
```

defined in a javaScript file called test.js which is reference from the following html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</head>
    <?php 
        echo "<script>test();</script>"; 
     ?>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I have verified that test.js works on it's own and the other javascript is being executed by the php. But I'm getting an undefined error.

```
Error: test() undefined
```

Can any one tell my how to properly reference a external javascript file from a php script?

Comment: is test.js in the same location as your php file?

Comment: no, the actual extension is "js/test.js". I omitted the "js/" in the example for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

put it in  your body and test it again

Comment: This didn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
    <?php 
        echo "<tag onClick='test()'>text text text </tag>"; 
     ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1- run the function manualy not with php : 
do some thing like :

```
<body onload ="alert('test');test();">
```

if worked test it:

```
<body onload ="alert('test');<?php echo "test();";?>">
```

if not worked your javascript function is not ok.

Comment: Why two answers? You could have edited the first one.

Answer (score 0):

It should just work, have you really tried it like this? :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            echo "<script>test();</script>"; 
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">','your_function();','</script>';
```